# Exception on Selenium Grid program

Tags: selenium-grid

Have started the hub and registered the node. Then wrote a program in eclipse:

after running the program i am getting below exception:-
Exception in thread "main" java. lang.Class  Cast Exception: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map.

the remote web driver is :

Remote Web Driver driver = new Remote Web Driver(client URL,capability);

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same error. The problem was in class org.openqa.selenium.remote.**RemoteWebDriver** (75):

```
Map<String, Object> rawCapabilities = (Map<String, Object>) response.getValue();
```

It's happened because I've given the wrong URL parameter for RemoteWebDriver():

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/"), capability);
```

That's why response had a String type.
Please check your url. It should be:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

I hope it will help you :)